# Использование формальных параметров

Tags: unix

Помогите, пожалуйста, найти информацию по "использование формальных параметров в UNIX".

Comment: Обычно если речь идет о формальных (а так же фактических) параметрах то это скорее программирование или я чего-то не знаю о никсах.

Answer (score 1):

Почитать можно, например, здесь: [терминал и командная строка](http://www.openspin.org/materials/courses/admin/ch02.html#shell-base), [параметры bash и расширения параметров](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/l-bash-parameters/).